# Is it possible to "save/convert" a 3D plot into a FBX or OBJ file to use in softwares like blender or maya?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export, generative-art, 3d-printing

Suppose you run a code to plot:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

or

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

or

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

or

(other kind of routine that returns you a 3D surface).

All of these codes generates a 3D surface and as we know Mathematica, creates a interactive space so that we can rotate and move the entire generated graphic. Now, given a code (whatever it is) to plot a 3D surface, I want to export the 3D graphic in common 3D art extensions, like FBX or OBJ. In summary, my question is:

> How can I save a 3D surface into a OBJ or FBX file?

Answer (score 0):

These are all handled by [Export](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html).  There is a dedicated help page for 3d geometry and modeling formats:

```mathematica
(* define the surface *)
example = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]

(* export in desired format, e.g., .obj, .stl *)
Export["example.obj", example]

(* reimport it to visualize if you wish *)
Import["example.obj"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with `Blender` you must export the surface and its mesh (if you want the mesh) separately. In Blender you can overlay them again.

Create and export surface

```
plot =
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   Mesh -> 0,
   PlotPoints -> 16,
   PlotRange -> All];

Export["yourpath" <> "yourname" <> "Plot.obj", plot];
```

Create and export surface mesh

```
mesh =
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   ContourStyle -> None,
   Mesh -> 6,
   PlotPoints -> 16,
   PlotRange -> All];

Export["yourpath" <> "yourname" <> "Mesh.obj", mesh];
```

Please study [Animating Mathematica surfaces with Blender: Surface creation & Ex-/Import](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2293492?source=frontpage-latest-news)

Google "Mathematica and Blender" to get more links and videos